# Is it correct to say "the Congress"?

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

Why is *Congress* used without the definite article *the*?

Comment: Proper nouns do not need determiners.

Comment: This is something that varies from organization to organization, and also with the way it's being used in the sentence.

Comment: Pedantically, it is _supposed_ to be referred to as 'the Congress' but most people just say 'Congress'. As to why they prefer that, that is a hard question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and, as regards the answer one at which I can only make a guess.

Perhaps because *Congress*, whether one is speaking of the *Houses of Congress*, or the ruling body of any organisation, the word has an especially grand ring about it.

Similarly if one is speaking of *Parliament*, meaning Westminster, one would not use the article. But if one were speaking, let's say, about another country, let's say Sierra Leone, one might say, showing a photograph, something like: 'the parliament meets in this building'.

But generally if you are having a detailed discussion about a particular country, the article might well be omitted. I believe it to be the same for *Congress*